# Как сделать выравнивание текста по наклонной линии?

Tags: html, css, css3

Даже примера кода нету : так как в голову не приходит как сделать

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Гуру CSS3 как такое реализовать ?

[Источник](https://toster.ru/q/340176)

Нашёл интересный вариант решение [Пример](http://htmlhook.ru/podrobno-o-css-shapes.html)

Вопрос задал на [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38857192/how-to-align-text-on-a-sloping-line)

Решение нашлось на SO

```css
.element{
  shape-outside: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/bf/Triangle-grey.svg/2000px-Triangle-grey.svg.png);
  shape-image-threshold: 0.2;
  float: left;
  height: 300px;
  padding: 0 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h2>CSS shapes / dLotus</h2>
  <img class='element' src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/bf/Triangle-grey.svg/2000px-Triangle-grey.svg.png" alt="">
  <div>
      <p>Lorem ipsum…Lorem ipsum…Lorem ipsum…Lorem ipsum…Lorem ipsum…Lorem ipsum…Lorem ipsum…Lorem ipsum…Lorem ipsum…Lorem ipsum…Lorem ipsum…Lorem ipsum…Lorem ipsum…Lorem ipsum…Lorem ipsum…Lorem ipsum…Lorem ipsum…Lorem ipsum…Lorem ipsum…Lorem ipsum…Lorem ipsum…Lorem ipsum…Lorem ipsum…Lorem ipsum…Lorem ipsum…Lorem ipsum…Lorem ipsum…Lorem ipsum…Lorem ipsum…Lorem ipsum…Lorem ipsum…Lorem ipsum…Lorem ipsum…Lorem ipsum…Lorem ipsum…Lorem ipsum…Lorem ipsum…Lorem ipsum…Lorem ipsum…Lorem ipsum…Lorem ipsum…Lorem ipsum…Lorem ipsum…Lorem ipsum…Lorem ipsum…Lorem ipsum…Lorem ipsum…Lorem ipsum…</p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Это круто ARPIL GOYAL выдал 100% результат

Comment: кучу br городить не вариант

Comment: треугольник с боку не интересует , это я сам могу

Comment: *это я сам могу* -- ну, если это сработает, то это достойно быть ответом. Потом, может, кто-то добавит свои альтерантивы, но надо ж с чего-то начинать.

Comment: D-side нужен текст расположенный таким образом , а треугольник с боку мне По боку

Comment: Если у вас подозрения, что вопрос может быть понят  неправильно, отредактируйте его.

Comment: Думаю - вот решение: [Создание непрямоугольных макетов при помощи CSS-форм](http://frontender.info/css-shapes/) Речь идёт о CSS-формах и регионах. [Примеры всяческие](https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/). Ещё одна [статья](http://htmlhook.ru/css3-regions.html) хорошая.

Comment: Можно использовать [shape-outside](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/s/shape-outside/). Это на порядок ближе к тому вопросу, на который здесь пытались ответить.

Comment: ассоциация:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38857192/

Comment: http://joxi.ru/l2Z6oQqhwezNz2

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Почти ничего сложного, если не бояться замарать ручки дикими костылями)

Вижу два варианта решения:

**Использование shape-outside**

Но, к сожалению, этот вариант абсолютно не кроссбраузерный и работает только в webkit-движках: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-shapes

**Куча блоков**

В варианте с треугольным обтеканием это легко реализовать и автоматизировать процесс с помощью JS. Я считаю этот вариант вполне приемлемым, если того требует задача. Конечно, автоматизировать создание блоков в помощью js будет весьма затруднительно, если форма обтекания сложная.

В своем примере я использовал оба варианта.

С шейпами все ясно: по трем точкам нарисовал область обтекания и готово.

"Кучу блоков" я наплодил с помощью js: создал один блок шириной 300px и с помощью js наплодил после него потомков, каждый короче на 10px.

Пример на jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ipshenicyn/h2o9fbav/2/

**HTML**

```
<div class="shape-left"></div>
<div class="shape-right"></div>
<p>очень много текста</p>
```

**CSS**

Код треугольников обтекания:

`.shape-left` - это блок, который я буду плодить с помощью js

`.shape-right` - блок с использованием `shape-outside`

```
.shape-left{
    float: left;
    width: 300px;
    height: 10px;
    clear: both;
}
.shape-right{
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    float: right;
    shape-outside: polygon(400px 0, 400px 400px, 0 400px);
}
```

**JS**

Код, который множит `.shape-left` с убыванием ширины, создавая тем самым треугольную область:

```
var $el = $('.shape-left'),
    width = $el.width(),
    count = width / 10;

for(var i = 0; i < count; i++){
    width = $el.width();
    $el = $el.clone().css('width',width-10).insertAfter($el);
}
```

Comment: @ИванПшеницын, вы абсолютно правы. в FireFox принятое решение на [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38857192/how-to-align-text-on-a-sloping-line) не работает. А ваше - подходит. Вам плюс. Вот скриншот: http://i.stack.imgur.com/VfiwW.png

Comment: Согласен. FireFox 49.0.1 SO не работает:)

Comment: http://joxi.ru/l2Z6oQqhwezNz2