# Распределение текста по наклонной ( часть 2 )

Tags: css, css3

Мой вопрос продолжение [этой](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/549173/33274) темы , выбрал из вариантов на SO и на ruSO самый простой вариант а это такой :

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.text-body {
  width: 500px;
  text-align: justify;
  line-height: 22px;
}

.shape {
  height: 22px;
  float: right;
  clear: right;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 0 8px;
}

.wrap {
  width: 300px;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <span>
  <div class="shape" style="width: 200px"></div>
  <div class="shape" style="width: 180px"></div>
  <div class="shape" style="width: 160px"></div>
  <div class="shape" style="width: 140px"></div>
  <div class="shape" style="width: 120px"></div>
  <div class="shape" style="width: 100px"></div>
  <div class="shape" style="width: 80px"></div>
  <div class="shape" style="width: 60px"></div>
  <div class="shape" style="width: 40px"></div>
  <div class="shape" style="width: 20px"></div>
</span>
  <div class="text-body">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Сам вопрос в том каким образом убрать расстояние между словами вызванное при `text-align:justify;` ? (скрин пробемы)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Так в этом и плюс justify если уберите его и все будет как должно быть. Или конечно что странно используйте дополнительные блоки внутри строк. Иначе используйте text-justify к примеру text-justify: inter-character;

Проверил поддержку все пока плачевно http://caniuse.com/#search=text-justify

Вот решение при помощи Jquery https://stackoverflow.com/a/24695835/5433400

Comment: я не понял о этом : text-justify: inter-character; что это ? и покажите как у вас вышло

Comment: Да к сожалению этот способ не подойдет. т.к. не поддерживается большинством браузеров данная директива указывает как именно использовать justify https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-justify

Comment: и даже на caninuse сказано что поддерживается IE и Edge так же не работает

Comment: Согласен, после публикации проверил и поправил свое сообщение. Но использовать можно при условиях, думаю станет нормой. А сейчас используется distribute

Comment: Если английский не проблема, вот решение при помощи jq https://stackoverflow.com/a/24695835/5433400