# Разместить текст под наклоном

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, текст

Как можно разместить текст под наклоном, как это на картинке?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
h1 {
  line-height: 1;
  color: green;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 15px;
}

p {
  text-align: justify;
  color: darkolivegreen;
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-size: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>Природа</h1>
  <p>Земля – это чудесная планета, ее природа разнообразна. Природа нашей планеты – это совокупность каждого элемента: физических естественных и материальных. Природой можно называть только то, что создавалось без непосредственного участия человека. Природа
    также представляет собой все физические, биохимические процессы на планете, а также жизнь в целом. Люди также являются частью природы, однако их зачастую рассматривают отдельно. В основном понятие «природа» относится только к животному миру и неживой
    природе. Обобщить понятием природы можно совокупность растений и животных, а иногда и явления неживого мира, которые напрямую влияют на живые организмы. Естественная среда обитания тех или иных организмов также считается природой. Это может быть экологическая
    система, представители животного, растительного миров, объекты вроде гор и склонов и так далее.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как сделать выравнивание текста по наклонной линии?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/549173/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```css
.conteiner {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}

.h1-wrapper {
  float: left;
  clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 0, 0 100%);
  width: 50%;
  height: 500px;
  shape-outside: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 0, 0 100%);
}

h1 {
  width: 50%;
  height: 500px;
  line-height: 1;
  color: green;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 15px;
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(150px, 200px);
}

p {
  width: 50%;
  height: 500px;
  text-align: justify;
  color: darkolivegreen;
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-size: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="h1-wrapper">
    <h1>Природа</h1>
  </div>

  <p>Земля – это чудесная планета, ее природа разнообразна. Природа нашей планеты – это совокупность каждого элемента: физических естественных и материальных. Природой можно называть только то, что создавалось без непосредственного участия человека. Природа
    также представляет собой все физические, биохимические процессы на планете, а также жизнь в целом. Люди также являются частью природы, однако их зачастую рассматривают отдельно. В основном понятие «природа» относится только к животному миру и неживой
    природе. Обобщить понятием природы можно совокупность растений и животных, а иногда и явления неживого мира, которые напрямую влияют на живые организмы. Естественная среда обитания тех или иных организмов также считается природой. Это может быть экологическая
    система, представители животного, растительного миров, объекты вроде гор и склонов и так далее.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Сегодня Вы дежурный по `shape-outside` )))

Comment: @UModeL, нет... Я седня просто бездельничаю...  ***кайфую***  ))))

Comment: ага. Значит, _Sevastopol'_ дежурный ))

Answer (score 2):

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.container {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  width: 800px;
  height: 600px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

p {
  text-align: justify;
  color: darkolivegreen;
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.left {
  float: left;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  shape-outside: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 0% 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 0% 100%);
  shape-margin: 1rem;
}

h1 {
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size: 7rem;
  line-height: 1;
  color: green;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 15px;
  transform: rotate(-39deg) translateX(4rem) translateY(-45%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    <h1>Природа</h1>
  </div>
  <p>Земля – это чудесная планета, ее природа разнообразна. Природа нашей планеты – это совокупность каждого элемента: физических естественных и материальных. Природой можно называть только то, что создавалось без непосредственного участия человека. Природа также представляет собой все физические, биохимические процессы на планете, а также жизнь в целом. Люди также являются частью природы, однако их зачастую рассматривают отдельно. В основном понятие «природа» относится только к животному миру и неживой природе. Обобщить понятием природы можно совокупность растений и животных, а иногда и явления неживого мира, которые напрямую влияют на живые организмы. Естественная среда обитания тех или иных организмов также считается природой. Это может быть экологическая система, представители животного, растительного миров, объекты вроде гор и склонов и так далее.</p>
</div>
```